# While removing html text from column, object of type 'float' has no len() error is occuring

Tags: pandas, data-science, nlp

I am using an amazon dataset to do sentiment analysis. Dataset content is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcKZp.png

dataset con be found on:
https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/amazon-reviews-unlocked-mobile-phones

I am trying to remove html from `Review` column. 
This is what I am doing. Note: dataset is assigned to `df`.

```
df_removedNoise = []
def removingHTML(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').get_text()
    return soup

def removingNoise(text):
    html_removed = removingHTML(text)
    return html_removed

for i in df["Reviews"]:
    text = removingNoise(i)
    df_removedNoise.append(text)
```

Even though Reviews column has object as a datatype, I am still getting an error like.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-3591f5d7a54f> in <module>
      9 
     10 for i in df["Reviews"]:
---> 11     df_removedNoise.append(removingNoise(i))

<ipython-input-83-3591f5d7a54f> in removingNoise(text)
      5 
      6 def removingNoise(text):
----> 7     html_removed = removingHTML(text)
      8     return html_removed
      9 

<ipython-input-83-3591f5d7a54f> in removingHTML(text)
      1 df_removedNoise = []
      2 def removingHTML(text):
----> 3     soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').get_text()
      4     return soup
      5 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, **kwargs)
    244         if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
    245             markup = markup.read()
--> 246         elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
    247                 (isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b'<' in markup)
    248                 or (isinstance(markup, str) and not '<' in markup)

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't understood what you mean with "remove html from Review column". could you explain it please?

Comment: What i meant was to remove HTML, XML, etc. markup and metadata from text.

Comment: Thanks @Erfan. I made a minor mistake while removing NaN values. That why i was having that error. Cheers!

Comment: Do you mind if I post it as answer, so you can accept it

Comment: Sure. I dont have any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `NaN` with `df[df['Reviews'].isnull()]`, if you find any try to `dropna` first